# RoR - ActionView Template Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, actionview

I'm trying to implement new redmine and then migrate my data from old redmine to new redmine.
But there is an template error showing in the log

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `is_closed?' for nil:NilClass):
    6: <h3><%= format_activity_day(day) %></h3>
    7: <dl>
    8: <% sort_activity_events(@events_by_day[day]).each do |e, in_group| -%>
    9:   <dt class="<%= e.event_type %> <%= "grouped" if in_group %> <%= User.current.logged? && e.respond_to?(:event_author) && User.current == e.event_author ? 'me' : nil %>">
    10:   <%= avatar(e.event_author, :size => "24") if e.respond_to?(:event_author) %>
    11:   <span class="time"><%= format_time(e.event_datetime, false) %></span>
    12:   <%= content_tag('span', h(e.project), :class => 'project') if @project.nil? || @project != e.project %>
  app/models/issue.rb:677:in `closed?'
  app/models/issue.rb:57:in `block in <class:Issue>'
```

I guess this monday is occured when the css is rendered.

Is there any idea about this problem?
or how to log and find the real cause of the problem?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.5-stable/app/models/issue.rb#L677 check this. It looks like your issue does not have status at all.

Comment: @gotva you're right! thanks man! if you want you can create an answer with same content as your comment and I will upvote and mark it as right, thanks!